# Sencha Desktop Packager executable

Tags: extjs

I have built a desktop version of my extjs app using Sencha desktop packager trial. It has created an output folder with a lot of dll files and an .exe file. The executable runs ok when i open it from within this folder but once i move the .exe outside it no longer runs. So it seems it is dependent on the other files generated along with it.

1. Am i doing something wrong here or is it supposed to be like this? Is it possible to get a single executable that will run on client machine?
2. Secondly after installation, is it possible to do automatic updates (or at least prompt for an update) based on version number?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean deploy them? Desktop applications will work only in the system where it is installed. You probably can copy the directory as such wherever you need

Comment: Sorry wrong choice of words from me. What i meant was providing users with this executable. I know i can copy the whole directory but would prefer a single file installer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like InnoSetup in order to automate the installation of the whole App directory on a foreign computer.